# MAPPLY across a vector in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I've seen several examples on Google, but still don't understand quite well how it works

here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a text array

```
> V <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff")
> V
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee" "ff"
```

i would like as an output an array of length length(V)-2 (=4)
composed of

```
[1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"
```

which is a vector with the concatenations of 3 successive elements of V

i'm thinking of using something like mapply

```
mapply(function(x,i){paste(x[i:i+2],sep="",collapse="")},V,1:(length(V)-2))
```

but thats not the right syntax

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in case your project needs many successive elements. There are other approaches, `mapply` is just one:

```
mapply(function(x,y) paste(V[x:y], collapse=""), 1:(length(V)-2), 3:length(V))
#[1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"
```

---

As per your comments, you can create a function and use `lapply` for a list:

```
paste2 <- function(vec, n=3) {
  mapply(function(x,y) paste(vec[x:y], collapse=""), 1:(length(vec)-(n-1)), n:length(vec))
}

## single vector still works
paste2(V)
#[1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"

## with list
lst <- rep(list(V), 2)
lapply(lst, paste2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"
```

Comment: thanks. i'm trying to do the next step alone. what i want to do is to apply this mapply function to a list of such character vectors so id like V to be a variable ideally...

Comment: I added a functional method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any fancy `mapply` for this:

```
n = length(V)
paste0(V[1:(n - 2)], V[2:(n - 1)], V[3:n])
```

Here's a parametric solution, you still don't need `mapply`:

```
i = 3
apply(matrix(V, nrow = length(V) + 1, ncol = i)[1:(length(V) - i + 1), ],
      MARGIN = 1, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
```

You could functionalize this:

```
f = function(V, i) {
  apply(matrix(V, nrow = length(V) + 1, ncol = i)[1:(length(V) - i + 1), ],      
        MARGIN = 1, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
}
```

You could then apply it to a list of vectors like this:

```
lapply(list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), letters), f, i = 3)

# [[1]]
# [1] "abc" "bcd"
#
# [[2]]
#  [1] "abc" "bcd" "cde" "def" "efg" "fgh" "ghi" "hij" "ijk" "jkl" "klm" "lmn" "mno" "nop" "opq"
# [16] "pqr" "qrs" "rst" "stu" "tuv" "uvw" "vwx" "wxy" "xyz"
```

You *would* need `mapply` (and you could use it with the function) if you had several different vectors *and* for each vector you wanted a concatenation of a *different* number of elements.

Comment: Your second block produces 9 each of `"aabbcc" "ddeeff"`

Comment: Oops, had a couple bugs, but fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative using `apply()` and `embed()`

```
rev(apply(embed(rev(V),3), 1, paste, collapse=""))
# [1] "aabbcc" "bbccdd" "ccddee" "ddeeff"
```

Comment: Or without all the reversing and `apply()` you could do `do.call(paste0, data.frame(embed(V, 3))[3:1])`.  Nice idea with `embed()`

Comment: thanks guys !! so many answers in such a short period of time ! it's great !